# How can I put `gjslint` back into the correct PATH?

Tags: terminal

I am using ATOM editor. I un-installed jslint and jshint because the warning/error colors stopped appearing - obv not the smartest way to debug. Now, when I reinstalled I receive two error messages... one for emmet and the other gjslint

I have no idea why my other packages are working properly. I know this is a newbie question but I am a little unsure where to start. Also, I do not know what system files would clear these in order to cleanly reinstall my community packages. Thank you for taking a second with my seemingly easy problem.

These are the 2 errors showing up in the console (linter is not working):

1.)

Loading Emmet extensions from ~/emmet
/Users/r.a.white/.atom/packages/emmet/lib/emmet.coffee:156 Emmet: no such extension folder: /Users/r.a.white/emmet
loadExtensions @ /Users/r.a.white/.atom/packages/emmet/lib/emmet.coffee:156
/Users/r.a.white/.atom/packages/linter/lib/linter-registry.js:154

2.)

[Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at /Users/r.a.white/.atom/packages/linter-gjslint/node_modules/atom-linter/lib/helpers.js:130
    at run (/Users/r.a.white/.atom/packages/git-plus/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:75)
    at /Users/r.a.white/.atom/packages/git-plus/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:92
    at flush (/Users/r.a.white/.atom/packages/git-plus/node_modules/core-js/modules/_microtask.js:18)
    at process._tickCallback...

all packages were working before uninstall. My other packages are running smooth. Thank you

Comment: Im having the same issue. did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Delayed answer, my apologies.

For the emmet extension error all you need to do is create an empty folder named 'emmet' under the user profile. So in this example, I created a file under my r.a.white user. For some reason the extension looks for a folder named emmet that was never created. I don't know why, but this obv fixes.

If you have errors with the eslint or gslint PATH then learning about the PATH and everything around it was the way to go. I understand why this question wasn't answered - It is a fundamentals type of question. I found this video from Andrew Mead did the trick for PATH understanding:

https://youtu.be/nxxl2H_TOTc?list=PLMWjeRChIK6bnp6qaS3rxLGCpc9aQYzEE

I hope you already found the help you needed but I hope this can help someone else next time :)